# Grouping Nested \newenvironment (Subsections & Sections)

Tags: environments, page-breaking

I'm creating a homework template, and using `\newenvironment` to create "Exercise", "Sub-Exercise", and "Solution" environments, so that I can nest Solutions within Sub-Exercises, and Sub-Exercises within Exercises.

The environments:

```
\newcounter{ExerciseNumber}[chapter]
\newcounter{SubExerciseNumber}[section]

\newenvironment{Exercise}{
    \clearpage
    \refstepcounter{ExerciseNumber}
    \section{Exercise \theExerciseNumber}
}{
    \clearpage
}

\newenvironment{SubExercise}{
    \vspace{10pt}
    \refstepcounter{SubExerciseNumber}
    \subsection{Exercise \theExerciseNumber.\theSubExerciseNumber}
}{
    \stepcounter{SubExerciseNumber}
}

\newenvironment{Solution}[0]{
    \paragraph{Solution}\hspace{0pt}\par
}{
}
```

And how I'm using the environments:

```
\begin{Exercise}\label{Exercise:1-A}% Exercise 1-A
\lipsum[1-1]


\begin{SubExercise}\label{Exercise:1-A-1}% Exercise 1-A-1
\lipsum[2-2]

\begin{Solution}
\lipsum[3-3]
\end{Solution}
\end{SubExercise}


\begin{SubExercise}\label{Exercise:1-A-3}% Exercise 1-A-3
\lipsum[4-4]

\begin{Solution}
\lipsum[5-5]
\end{Solution}
\end{SubExercise}

\end{Exercise}
```

I am using the `report` document class.

The problem that I'm having is with how to keep content grouped together appropriately.

Essentially, the above environments and their content should follow this priority:

Solution > Sub-Exercise > Exercise

Currently, though, I am getting output like this:

[image]

I've been playing around with `\pagebreak` and `\nopagebreak`, but other than adding `\nopagebreak[4]` right after the section/subsection/paragraph headings, `\pagebreak[0-3]` and `\nopagebreak[0-3]` don't seem to do much to affect page breaking priority (as in, there seems to be no noticeable difference between 0 and 3, whereas 4 forces the break or lack thereof, which is not the binary choice that I always want).

Comment: You increment SubExerciseNumber twice in every Subexercise, once before and again after.  Also, I'm not sure tying the exercises to sections is a good idea.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, yes, I'm aware I'm incrementing it twice. For this particular assignment, I'm only answering odd questions, hence the double increment. As for tying the exercises to sections/sub-exercises to subsections, that's just to take advantage of section heading formatting, as well as for easy TOC listing, but I'm open to changing it.

Comment: Latex uses \@startsection to handle the section formatting (see source2e.pdf in the base folder).  The first argument is the name of the counter.  The TOC formatting is handled by \l@section or \@figure etc. using the same name.